# form user control not in right location

Tags: c#

I have a c# form app that has a few user controls on the main form. When a co-worker runs the app on his PC, the location of one of the user controls changes to the wrong spot. Another user control right above it is in the correct location. The locations of both are set in the designer when dropping the control onto the main form; i.e., the locations are not set programmatically. Would anyone have any idea why the location of one user control would become wrong? AutoScaleMode of all controls is set to Dpi.

Comment: Overall structure is unknown.  Are these directly on the form itself, or in another control, such as a `Panel` or `TableLayoutPanel`?  Are there any methods/event handlers related to size or position involved?

Comment: Kindly attach the images of correct form, and problem containing form.

Comment: You'd probably get better answers if you post the code that shows the `UserControl` as well as screen shots of the different behavior

Comment: Does Your coworker use windows 7 ?

Comment: Could you try set `AutoScaleMode` to `AutoScaleMode.Font`?

Comment: Why was my answer deleted ? This was a definite issue at our company. Regarding .net 2.0 as i remember correctly.